# LimitInternalRecursion or .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been tasked with maintaining a website that i do not know much about and every 20 minutes i keep getting this problem in the log file

```
Request exceeded the limit of 2000 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

My .htaccess file is available here - http://pastebin.com/N4GQx73x

I've even tried a few fixes i found on the net using

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(stats/|404.php|failed_auth.html|error/).* [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

To no avail. mod_rewrite is beyond me. However i think it's possibly the following 3 lines that is causing the error but not quite sure which condition is causing it.

```
(5) strip matching prefix: /var/www2/blogs.*DELETED*.co.za/index.php -> index.php
(4) add subst prefix: index.php -> /index.php
(1) [perdir /var/www2/blogs.*DELETED*.co.za/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

I've gone through as many articles as i could find but i just cannot seem to narrow down the cause

Please help me

Comment: Try to make your rewrite rules to produce external redirects.  Then test with browser and see where is redirection loop.

Comment: Rewrite conditions are valid only for the next rewrite rule. There are 11 rules in the .htaccess file in your link so I guess rewrite conditions to prevent loops like these: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` have to be inserted before each rule. There are other ways to do it, but this one is a general one that works for most rules.

Comment: Last rule is this one: `RewriteRule . index.php [L]` Try adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` before that rule and all other rules. That should stop any loop, which is what you have according to the error message.

Comment: will make changes and revert ;) thanks a mil

Comment: @faa Added your suggestions (http://pastebin.com/vHJwviih) Will let you know if i keep getting that error.

Comment: Remove the `[OR]` from the first line. Default is `AND` and is better that way.

Comment: @faa So it should look like this ?    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [AND]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

Comment: No need to include the `AND`, is the default behavior.

Comment: @faa that was how i had it before i added OR. on another note i have managed to resolve it using the standard multisite code that has to be added when setting up wordpress MU. i really appreciate your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Just a note on how i solved it. i updated my existing .htaccess with the standard code that is given to you when setting up the wordpress MU install. No more loops!